# Angular v11 to v12 throws not assignable to the same property in base type FormArray

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular12

After upgrading Angular version 11 to 12, one of class which extends FormArray gives below error

> Property 'controls' in type 'CustomFormArray' is not assignable to the
> same property in base type 'FormArray'.

**However, same CustomFormArray was working fine in Angular version 11**

```
import { FormArray, AbstractControl, ValidationErrors } from '@angular/forms';

export class CustomFormArray extends FormArray implements AbstractControl {
  /* **Ang 12 gives below error for controls when you hover property controls**
     Property 'controls' in type 'CustomFormArray' is not assignable to the same property in 
     base type 'FormArray'.
  */
  public controls: CustomFormArray[];
  constructor() {
    super([]);
  }
  /*    **Ang 12 gives below error for parent when you hover property parent**
        Property 'parent' in type 'CustomFormArray' is not assignable to the same property in 
        base type 'AbstractControl'.
        Type 'CustomFormArray' is not assignable to type 'FormArray | FormGroup'.(2416)
        Property 'parent' in type 'CustomFormArray' is not assignable to the same property in 
        base type 'FormArray'.
        Type 'CustomFormArray' is not assignable to type 'FormArray | FormGroup'.(2416)
  */
  public get parent(): CustomFormArray {
    return super.parent as CustomFormArray;
  }
  /*    Ang 12 gives below error for push method
        Types of property 'push' are incompatible.
        Type '(control: CustomFormArray, skip?: boolean) => void' is not assignable to 
        type '(control: AbstractControl, options?: { emitEvent?: boolean; }) => void'.
  */
  public push(control: CustomFormArray, skip: boolean = false) {
    super.push(control);
  }
}
```

CustomFormArray Works fine for Angular 11 - [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-forms-formarray-example-pzo7yi?file=src/app/custom-form-array.ts)

CustomFormArray throws error for Angular 12 - [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-forms-formarray-example-3gkcm1?file=src/app/custom-form-array.ts)

If we change different name for method push some other name like pushNew and now Error goes away!
Please advise why angular v12 does not uses same push method from FormArray!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to go to https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=11.0-12.0 for all update information.

In your case

> If your app has custom classes that extend FormArray or FormGroup classes and override the above-mentioned methods, you may need to update your implementation